# How to pass output from an upstream project to downstream projects in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to use a project's *results* to generate parameters that can be passed down to multiple child projects using s something like the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

Specifically, I want to make a parent project as a sort of *resource manager* for my testing servers.  Once the project is build, there are a number of complex test suites to run and only so many test servers.  Rather than hard-code which test servers I want to run each test, I want the *resource manager* project to:

1. Determine which servers are available/operational.
2. Select subsets of the available servers for each test.
3. Pass sets of IP addresses down to multiple projects to be run in parallel.

I know I could probably do this by having the *resource manager* write these parameters onto the filesystem and configure the child projects to read from those files, but I'm sure that this is the type of problem already solved by a plugin.  I just don't see how to the trigger plugin can retrieve arbitrary parameters from its own build output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin, but it works along the same principle: it reads a properties file from filesystem, and loads those as Environment Variables available to any step of the project. **[EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)**

It does have ability to generate a list of properties from a script, rather than a properties file.